# Which answer should I accept if multiple answers to my question are correct (or identical)?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

Today two answers were posted to my [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/8118/teenage-girl-saved-alone-on-the-ship) and both of them are correct. So I accepted the one which had better presentation and was answered first. Though I did it, for future reference, what is the etiquette i.e. which one should be accepted in these cases? The one which is answered fist or what is good to see? Does it solely depend on the asker which one to accept?

Comment: Read this similar discussion for reference http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80788/which-answer-should-i-accept

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is entirely on your discretion. The whole point is for you to decide which answer you find as a better explanation, regardless of time posted.

Comment: I agree - the time posted should really IMHO only be used if two almost identical answers are posted.

Comment: I think this question also points to the need to not accept an answer too quickly. Sometimes an early answer is sufficient but a fuller answer follows a few days later.

Comment: on this site i tend to let my questiosn cook for a while before i decide if i'm going to accept an answer.